# How to display related post from same category in single.php

Tags: posts, categories

How to display related the post from same category in single.php. I have tried but it was not working.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

On your single.php template, you need to load the category term(s), and then run a query to get other posts. In my example, I load posts from a single category. We have Wordpress SEO plugin installed which allows you to select a primary category if you decide to select several.

```
$related_articles = array();
$categories = get_the_category();

if($categories) {
   $category_id = $categories[0]->term_id;

   if(count($categories) > 1 && class_exists('WPSEO_Primary_Term')) {
      $primary_term = new WPSEO_Primary_Term('category', get_the_id());
      $category_id  = $primary_term->get_primary_term();
   }

   $related_articles = get_posts(array(
      'category'    => $category_id,
      'exclude'     => $post->ID,
      'numberposts' => 3,
      'order'       => 'DESC',
      'orderby'     => 'date',
      'post_status' => 'published',
      'post_type'   => 'post'
   ));
}
```

You can then loop through the related posts, if any:

```
<?php if($related_articles): ?>
   <section class="related-articles">
      <?php foreach($related_articles as $post): ?>
         <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
         <article>
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
         </article>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
      <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
   </section>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

To display related posts from the same category in a single post view `single.php`

```
// Get the current post ID
$current_post_id = get_the_ID();

// Get the current post categories
$categories = get_the_category($current_post_id);

// Get the first category (you can modify this logic based on your needs)
if (!empty($categories)) {
    $category_id = $categories[0]->term_id;

    // Custom query to get related posts from the same category
    $related_args = array(
        'category__in' => array($category_id),
        'post__not_in' => array($current_post_id),
        'posts_per_page' => 3, // Adjust the number of related posts to display
        'orderby' => 'rand', // Display related posts in random order
    );

    $related_query = new WP_Query($related_args);

    // Output related posts
    if ($related_query->have_posts()) {
        echo '<h3>Related Posts</h3>';
        echo '<ul>';
        while ($related_query->have_posts()) {
            $related_query->the_post();
            echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }

    // Restore original post data
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```